# Variável Google Script para modelo HTMLService

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Tenho um [script Google publicado](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1n6708vMYobSS9gC1uzHWG6Y8h6-uQ19miytFhOSyJVIzn7wy_Cxx4jXX/edit?usp=drive_web). Gostaria de poder selecionar uma opção de visualização entre duas alternativas baseado na escolha de senha. Tentei `if else statement`, `switch`, sem sucesso. Veja o [link](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1n6708vMYobSS9gC1uzHWG6Y8h6-uQ19miytFhOSyJVIzn7wy_Cxx4jXX/edit?usp=drive_web) e código dos dois gráficos Google abaixo:

Para ser claro, existem dois gráficos que gostaria de poder fazer a escolha de apenas uma visualização quando escolher o que desejo. Até agora só consigo escolher visualizar uma opção.

```
function doGet(passed) {

    switch(passed.parameter.form) {
        case '1':
            return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('IndexY').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
        break;
        case '2':
        default:
            return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
        return result;
    }
}

function onLogin(form) {
    if (form.username == "a") {
        var template =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Response');

        //Setup any variables that should be used in the page
        template.firstName = "Your name is here";
        template.username = form.username;

        return template.evaluate()
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .getContent();
    } 
    if (form.username == "b") {
        var templateb =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ResponseY');

        //Setup any variables that should be used in the page
        templateb.firstName = "Your name is here";
        templateb.username = form.username;

        return templateb.evaluate()
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .getContent();
    }
    else {
        throw "You could not be found in the database please try again.";
    }
}


function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename)
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .getContent();
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara.

Comment: Existem dois gráficos, gostaria de poder escolher uma alternativa de visualização. Observando o código é possível identificar dois createTemplateFromFile o que mostra a necessidade de tentar alternar entre duas páginas html.

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar...